# what to do with non-numeric predictor in plsreg1?

Tags: r, numeric

I am using the function ""plsreg1" in the "plsdepot" package to run a PLS regression.

As the package introduction states, in the argument "plsreg1(predictors, response, comps = 2, crosval = TRUE)", the predictors represents "A numeric matrix or data frame with the predictor variables (which may contain missing data)."

And the response represents "A numeric vector for the reponse variable. No missing data allowed."

My question is, what if some of my predictor are categorical variable ?
can I still use this package? How should I revise my script?

Example script from the package is as below

```
library(plsdepot)
data(cornell)

matrix of correlations
round(as.dist(cor(cornell)),3)

# partial least squares regression
mypls1 <- plsreg1(cornell[,1:7], cornell[,8,drop=F],comp=3)
mypls1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think if you recode the factors to numeric (`as.numeric(as.factor(letters))`) it should work. I don't know if correctly (I'm not familiar with the function or package).

Comment: yes, i can run the analysis after recode the factors to numeric. i am just not sure whether it is appropriate to do this. wouldn't it change the characteristic of the categorical variables?

Comment: In that case, I think the question should be migrated to crossvalidated.com